# Add text to a label control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Okay I have been fighting with this a few days and cannot find an answer anywhere.

I am using Framework 3.5 and -//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN

Now here is my question:

When I upgraded the Framework all of my vb.net pages stopped working.  I get 'Text' is not a member of 'label'.  They work just find before and now nothing i try is fixing this issue.  I am generally a C# coder however there is just to many pages to convert so I need a solution.

here is some samples of what I have tried:

```
Dim lbl As String = DirectCast(row.FindControl("labelID"), label).Text()
someLabel.Text = Trim(lbl.Text)

Dim lbl As label = TryCast(row.FindControl("labelID"), label)
someLabel.Text = Trim(lbl.Text)

Dim lbl As label = CType(row.FindControl("labelID"), label)  
someLabel.Text = Trim(lbl.Text)
```

Each try gives me the same error.  Am i missing a assembly reference or something?
here is the list I am using:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.SqlTypes
Imports System.Data.Sql
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Web.Mail
Imports System.Web.Configuration
Imports System.Object
Imports System.Web.UI.Control
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls.MultiView
Imports System.Collections.CollectionBase
```

**EDIT ::**

Okay I found the issue. I had a very old class that was interfering with the cast in the App_Code folder.  Once I removed the class I used this to define my Labels:

```
Dim lbl As String = CType(row.FindControl("LabelID"), label).Text
someLabel.Text = Trim(lbl)
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Text is property but you've .Text() in the first line..

Comment: I do however, the DirectCast line is the one that fails there because of the .Text()

Answer (score 0):

I use this for a listwiew I'm working. 
step value label to variable and then pass it to the same label

**C#**

```
            LinkButton btn = e.CommandSource as LinkButton;  // Identify the link button
            ListViewItem item = btn.NamingContainer as ListViewItem;
            Label lbl1 = item.FindControl("Label1") as Label;
              if (lbl1.Text != "1")
               {
                   lbl1.Text = "1";
               }
```

**VB**

```
            Dim btn As LinkButton = TryCast(e.CommandSource, LinkButton)
            ' Identify the link button
            Dim item As ListViewItem = TryCast(btn.NamingContainer, ListViewItem)
            Dim lbl1 As Label = TryCast(item.FindControl("Label1"), Label)
              If lbl1.Text <> "1" Then
                lbl1.Text = "1"
              End If
```